# percentage of a color/structure in image openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, mask

Is there an implement way or procedure to get an aproximation of the percentage of a structure/color in a image using opencv. I was attempting several methods by using masks, CLAHE, kernels, transformation...but don't really achieve what I am looking for. 
Let's suppose I want to count or detect the percentage of a structure which can have a color in a particulare image. For instance, if I have the following image:
[redeye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQPo9.jpg)
If I want to represent the percentage of blood vessels (those red ones) How shoul I proceed?.
This is what I  already tried but doesn't seem to be the optimal way:

```
path = 'C:/.../redeye.jpg'
img=cv2.imread(path)
#try with HSV (I already tried RGB transformation)
img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# lower mask (0-10)
lower_red = np.array([7,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# upper mask (170-180)
lower_red = np.array([170,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)



# join my masks
mask = mask0+mask1

# set my output img to zero everywhere except my mask
output_img = img.copy()
output_img[np.where(mask==0)] = 0
plt.imshow(output_img)
plt.show()
```